# Changing facebook Application name doesnot reflects in Android app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have used facebook sdk and created facebook application for login and sharing in Android application . All works great but when I tried renaming the facebook application , the new name doesnot reflects in Android app. It still shows the older name on authorizing screen . Is there something I am missing please help.